# spark-submit no class found - htrace

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I am trying to run the Spark example code HBaseTest from command line using spark-submit instead run-example, in that case, I can learn more how to run spark code in general.

However, it told me CLASS_NOT_FOUND about htrace since I am using CDH5.4. I successfully located the htrace jar file but I am having a hard time adding it to path.

This is the final spark-submit command I have but still have the class not found error.  Can anyone help me with this?

```
#!/bin/bash
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark

/bin/bash $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
--master yarn-client \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.HBaseTest \
--driver-class-path /etc/hbase/conf:$SPARK_HOME/examples/lib/*.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/lib/hbase/lib/*.jar \
--jars $SPARK_HOME/examples/lib/*.jar:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/lib/hbase/lib/*.jar \
$SPARK_HOME/examples/lib/*.jar \
myhbasetablename
```

Note: 
htrace-core-3.0.4.jar, htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar, htrace-core.jar are all located under '/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.2-1.cdh5.4.2.p0.2/lib/hbase/lib/'.

Answer (score 1):

I opened up the `$SPARK_HOME/conf/classpath.txt` and just added the `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar` to the end of the file.

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/ClassNotFoundException-org-apache-htrace-Trace-exception-in/m-p/29253/highlight/true#M915

Answer (score 0):

This is because Spark is unable to find the HBase jars or classes. For Spark-HBase integration, the best way is to add HBase libraries to Spark Classpath.

This can be done using the `compute-classpath.sh` script in `$SPARK_HOME/bin` folder.

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/HBase/lib/*

eg: export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/*
```

After this, restart Spark.

There you go :)