# Why doesn't the spark-submit package reference always work?

Tags: jar, apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming

So, I am running into the same issue that many are experiencing - see the error below.

```
WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (): java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/htrace/Trace
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.Trace
```

The instructions for fixing this seem to be missing, [incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055593/spark-submit-no-class-found-htrace), or [overly complex](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Apache-Hadoop-Concepts-and/Class-not-found-running-Spark-sample-hbase-importformat-py-in/td-p/27084). I've resolved other reference issues simply by adding them to the packages list in spark-submit. I've tried doing the same with this htrace dependency too, but with no luck.

This is my current spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --class com.biz.HbasePassthrough \
        --packages \
            org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.3.0,org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:1.0.0,org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:1.0.0,org.apache.hbase:hbase-server:1.0.0,org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.10:3.2.11,org.apache.htrace:htrace:3.1.0-incubating,org.apache.htrace:htrace-core:3.1.0-incubating,org.apache.htrace:htrace-hbase:3.1.0-incubating,org.apache.hbase:hbase-annotations:1.0.0 \
        ./my-spark_2.10-1.0.8.jar \
        >spark_log 2>&1
```

Output of `grep -n1 "htrace" spark_log`

```
8-org.json4s#json4s-jackson_2.10 added as a dependency
9:org.apache.htrace#htrace added as a dependency
10:org.apache.htrace#htrace-core added as a dependency
11:org.apache.htrace#htrace-hbase added as a dependency
12-org.apache.hbase#hbase-annotations added as a dependency
--
36-     found org.mortbay.jetty#jetty-util;6.1.26 in central
37:     found org.apache.htrace#htrace-core;3.1.0-incubating in central
38-     found org.apache.hbase#hbase-client;1.0.0 in central
--
75-     found com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.3.1 in central
76:     found org.apache.htrace#htrace;3.1.0-incubating in central
77:     found org.apache.htrace#htrace-hbase;3.1.0-incubating in central
78-:: resolution report :: resolve 6423ms :: artifacts dl 45ms
--
111-    org.apache.hbase#hbase-server;1.0.0 from central in [default]
112:    org.apache.htrace#htrace;3.1.0-incubating from central in [default]
113:    org.apache.htrace#htrace-core;3.1.0-incubating from central in [default]
114:    org.apache.htrace#htrace-hbase;3.1.0-incubating from central in [default]
115-    org.apache.kafka#kafka_2.10;0.8.1.1 from central in [default]
--
182-15/11/30 23:39:20 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/ubuntu/.ivy2/jars/json4s-jackson_2.10.jar at http://192.168.240.209:37644/jars/json4s-jackson_2.10.jar with timestamp 1448926760838
183:15/11/30 23:39:20 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/ubuntu/.ivy2/jars/htrace-core.jar at http://192.168.240.209:37644/jars/htrace-core.jar with timestamp 1448926760845
184:15/11/30 23:39:20 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/ubuntu/.ivy2/jars/htrace-hbase.jar at http://192.168.240.209:37644/jars/htrace-hbase.jar with timestamp 1448926760846
185-15/11/30 23:39:20 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/ubuntu/.ivy2/jars/hbase-annotations.jar at http://192.168.240.209:37644/jars/hbase-annotations.jar with timestamp 1448926760847
```

All of that output at the beginning of the job seems to suggest that it found the package and will use it successfully, but it doesn't work.

I did finally find something that I think got me past the issue - [here](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/oxCtDsblpv4). I adapted this by adding the following two lines to my spark-submit command above

```
    --driver-class-path "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar" \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar" \
```

Why didn't the packages reference work?